# Time zone conversion in SQL query

Tags: sql, oracle, gmt, timezone-offset

I am using a query to get some application Received Date from Oracle DB which is stored as GMT. Now I have to convert this to Eastern standard/daylight savings time while retrieving.
I am using the below query for this:

```
   select to_char (new_time(application_recv_date,'gmt','est'), 'MON dd, YYYY') from application
```

It works fine for Standard time. But for daylight savings time we need to convert it to 'edt' based on timezone info. I am not very sure on how to do this. Please help me out

Comment: For what **database** is this? Not all databases using SQL support the same ways of dealing with time zones.... please update your tags with the appropriate info - `oracle`, `sql-server`, `mysql`, `postgres` or whatever you're using!

Comment: Sorry missed it..Updated now (Oracle)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can use this query, without having to worry about timezone changes.

```
select to_char(cast(application_recv_date as timestamp) at time zone 'US/Eastern',
               'MON dd, YYYY'
              )
from application;
```

Ex:

EDT:

```
select cast(date'2014-04-08' as timestamp) d1,
       cast(date'2014-04-08' as timestamp) at time zone 'US/Eastern' d2
from dual;

D1                                 D2
---------------------------------- -------------------------------------------
08-APR-14 12.00.00.000000 AM       07-APR-14 08.00.00.000000 PM US/EASTERN
```

EST:

```
select cast(date'2014-12-08' as timestamp) d1,
       cast(date'2014-12-08' as timestamp) at time zone 'US/Eastern' d2
from dual;

D1                                 D2
---------------------------------- -------------------------------------------
08-DEC-14 12.00.00.000000 AM       07-DEC-14 07.00.00.000000 PM US/EASTERN
```

UPDATE:

Thanks to Alex Poole for reminding that, when timezone is not specified, local timezone is used for conversion.

To force the date to be recognized as GMT, use from_tz.

```
from_tz(cast(date'2014-12-08' as timestamp), 'GMT') at time zone 'US/Eastern'
```

Comment: I followed your steps. But then, why I am getting different dates d2 & d3 in the below code
 `select cast(date'2014-12-08' as timestamp) d1,
      new_time( cast(date'2014-12-08' as timestamp) ,'gmt','edt') d2,
       cast(date'2014-12-08' as timestamp) at time zone 'US/Eastern' d3
from dual`
D1 ==> 08-DEC-14 12.00.00.000000000 AM
D2 ==> 07-DEC-2014 20:00:00 
D3 ==> 07-DEC-14 01.30.00.000000000 PM US/EASTERN

Comment: @satyanarayana - `d2` is converting from GMT to EDT, which is an hour out from EatÂPeach's example because it should not be in daylight savings in December - using EST would work, but it's easier and safer to use regions. `d3` is comverting from your local timezone, not from GMT.

Comment: @Alex Poole - Thank you very much for letting me know that I was converting from local timezone rather than GMT.

Comment: @satyanarayana - if your source data is really GMT, not UK time (GMT/BST), then you can force it to be recognised like that: `select from_tz(cast(application_recv_date as timestamp), 'GMT') at time zone 'US/Eastern' from ...`.

Answer (score 5):

In Oracle, you can achieve this with below query:

```
Select current_timestamp, current_timestamp at time zone 'Australia/Sydney' from dual;
```

Where `Australia/Sydney` is the name of your timezone in which you want to convert your time.

Answer (score -1):

There already a function exists which converts the time of your needed column from one timezone to another:-

```
 convert_tz("columname or / the time you want to convert", fromTimeZone, ToTimeZone)
```

For Example:-
I want to convert time of dateTIme column from Indian Time (IST) to Brazil TimeZone as my host database time is by default in india it takes indian time:-

1. Indian Time is GMT+5:30
2. Brazil TIme is GMT-5:30

> convert_tz(dl.modified_datetime,'+5:30','-3:00') 'modified_time'

So, In this process you can convert it easily.