# Select all dates between two dates and display the unique count of inventory id

Tags: sql, oracle, date

Im using oracle db .I have 2 table specifically Inventory and grounding_info . Each inventory can have multiple grounding info or none. The table structure is as follows.

```
Inventory
---------              
Inventory_id


Grounding_info
--------------
Info_id
Inventory_id
Grounding_date
```

I want to get the count of inventories grounded on each date between a given date range. If  no inventory grounded on a date , that date should be displayed with count 0.

Please help..
I tried the  below query:

```
select tble.dte,count(distinct(groundinginfo.INVENTORY_ID)) cmt from ATL_GROUNDING_INFO groundinginfo
outer join (
    SELECT TO_DATE('2015/01/01 12:00:00 A.M.' ,'YYYY/MM/DD hh:mi:ss A.M.') - 1 + rownum AS dte FROM all_objects groundinginfo
    WHERE TO_DATE('2015/01/01 12:00:00 A.M.' ,'YYYY/MM/DD hh:mi:ss A.M.') - 1 + rownum <= TO_DATE('2015/04/01 11:59:59 P.M.' ,'YYYY/MM/DD hh:mi:ss P.M.') 
) tble
on groundinginfo.DATE_TURNED_IN = tble.dte
group by tble.dte
```

But it returned the error: "ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended"

Comment: So why tag with mysql? That said, issues of data display are generally best handled at the application level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this query:

```
SELECT tble.dte, COUNT(DISTINCT INVENTORY_ID) As cmt FROM ATL_GROUNDING_INFO groundinginfo
right join (
    SELECT TRUNC(TO_DATE('2015/01/01' ,'YYYY/MM/DD') - 1 + rownum) dte FROM DUAL
    CONNECT BY ROWNUM < 366 AND TRUNC(TO_DATE('2015/01/01' ,'YYYY/MM/DD') - 1 + rownum) <= TRUNC(TO_DATE('2015/04/01' ,'YYYY/MM/DD'))
) tble
on tble.dte = TRUNC(groundinginfo.DATE_TURNED_IN)
group by tble.dte
order by tble.dte ASC
```

Comment: well i tried with the below query

select tble.dte,count(distinct(groundinginfo.INVENTORY_ID))  cmt
from  ATL_GROUNDING_INFO  groundinginfo
outer join
(
SELECT TO_DATE('2015/01/01 12:00:00 A.M.' ,'YYYY/MM/DD hh:mi:ss A.M.') - 1 + rownum AS dte
FROM all_objects groundinginfo
WHERE TO_DATE('2015/01/01 12:00:00 A.M.' ,'YYYY/MM/DD hh:mi:ss A.M.') - 1 + rownum <= TO_DATE('2015/04/01 11:59:59 P.M.' ,'YYYY/MM/DD hh:mi:ss P.M.')
) tble
on groundinginfo.DATE_TURNED_IN = tble.dte 
group by tble.dte

Comment: but this one returned error
'ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended'

Comment: whe i use right join Im getting all the count as 0, eventhough there are inventory entries for that date

Comment: Sorry I interpreted this as a mysql question from the tags, you should maybe change your tags to oracle DB and put the query above into your question.

Comment: @Shini I have tried to fix your oracle query but I don't have a great deal of experience with it.

Comment: Thanks Kez. But i do get the above error when using outer join 
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Comment: Thanks Kez. This works fine.. Just out of curiosity, can you let me what is the significance of   CONNECT BY ROWNUM < 366

Comment: @Shini that specifies the max number of rows of the date table, which is just over a year (366 days). DUAL is a table with only one row and one column, but you can use CONNECT BY to artificially extend it to any number of rows for things like this. 366 is quite arbitrary but if you made the number lower it would return exactly the number of days you wanted and the WHERE clause would not be needed. For example `CONNECT BY ROWNUM <= 31` would give you all of January without the WHERE clause.

Comment: Ok.Thanks Kez... That helped me a lot.

Comment: Hi , can i get the dates between 'Thu Jan 01 05:00:00 GMT 2015' and 'Thu Apr 02 03:59:59 GMT 2015'  using the above query

Comment: @Shini The TRUNC function only returns a date - not a time.

Comment: The issue is tht my db is in GMT and my application rund in EST..  so few count mismatch due to the time zone issue

Comment: Check out this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22933608/time-zone-conversion-in-sql-query

Comment: Im using teh following query to get teh count of inventory in a following date rang. But my join condition is not working properly. So getting all count as 0. Pls assist.

Comment: SELECT tble.dte, COUNT(DISTINCT INVENTORY_ID)As cmt,groundinginfo.DATE_TURNED_IN
FROM ATL_GROUNDING_INFO groundinginfo right join (SELECT TO_DATE('03/11/2015 04:00:00','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') - 1
+ rownum dte FROM DUAL CONNECT BY ROWNUM < 366 AND TO_DATE('03/11/2015 04:00:00','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') - 1
+ rownum <= TO_DATE('04/02/2015 03:59:59','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')) tble on tble.dte
= (groundinginfo.DATE_TURNED_IN) group by tble.dte,groundinginfo.DATE_TURNED_IN order by tble.dte desc

Comment: Sorry but what you're trying to do changes things quite a lot - it is probably worth asking another question. The problem is that the table you are generating now has a specific time and date, so it won't join unless the date_turned_in is a date and time and exactly 04:00am.

Comment: Can i add filter condition to the below query to remove the inventory with grounded status != 'Ground'

Comment: 'SELECT tble.dte, COUNT(DISTINCT VIN) As cmt
FROM ATL_GROUNDING_REPORT groundinginfo right join (SELECT TRUNC(TO_DATE('2015/03/09 04:00:00 A.M.', 'YYYY/MM/DD hh:mi:ss A.M.') - 1
+ rownum) dte FROM DUAL CONNECT BY ROWNUM < 366 AND TRUNC(TO_DATE('2015/03/09 04:00:00 A.M.','YYYY/MM/DD hh:mi:ss A.M.') - 1
+ rownum) <= TRUNC(TO_DATE('2015/03/09 03:59:59 P.M.', 'YYYY/MM/DD hh:mi:ss P.M.'))) tble on tble.dte
= TRUNC(New_Time(groundinginfo.DATE_TURNED_IN,'GMT', 'EST')) 

group by tble.dte order by tble.dte desc;'