# Query should return result for sysdate @ specific time

Tags: sql, sql-server

My SQL server is hosted in EST timezone server. Hence, My query picks data from a specific table by converting date from EST TO SGT. My code continuously polls this table every 3 mints. But now we have to setup our query in such a way that it should start picking data only after 9 AM SGT and continue to do so until Close of SGP Business for current day. Could someone help me to write a query for this ?

Comment: can you not use SQL agent to execute this query on your schedule?

Comment: Do you mean something like [AT TIME ZONE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/at-time-zone-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: Really great description for Oracle: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22933608/time-zone-conversion-in-sql-query

Comment: If it is not too late to consider, you might find it easier to store dates in GMT. That way the date parameters will always need to be normalized by the sender. SQL Server 2016+ has access to the locale settings of the server.