# Convert sysdate to BST(British Summer Time)

Tags: sql, oracle, date, timezone

I have a Java api which gets the data from oracle database which is in ET timezone. I want to query that table using sysdate on 2 columns but the sysdate should be picked as current BST date value not as ET date value.

```
select * from customers where sysdate between mem_registered_date and mem_deregistered_date;
```

How this can be done? please help

Comment: See this post/answer -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/22935120/3715100

Comment: Wow, I didn't know Bangladesh Standard Time was so popular.

Comment: @MattJohnson-Pint Edited :)

Comment: What precisely is the data type of your column?

Comment: @BasilBourque datatype of columns is DATE

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to convert between time zones is to use a data type that understands time zones, a `TIMESTAMP`. Then when you've converted to the time zone you want then `CAST` it back to a `DATE` data type:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   customers
WHERE  CAST( SYSTIMESTAMP AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/London' AS DATE )
         BETWEEN mem_registered_date AND mem_deregistered_date;
```

I'm assuming that you want the current time in the United Kingdom (BST in summer and GMT in winter), if you want the time zone UTC+1 then use:

```
CAST( SYSTIMESTAMP AT TIME ZONE '+01:00' AS DATE )
```

Answer (score 2):

If querying a column with a date-only value, without any time-of-day nor any time zone, that is, a column of a type akin to the SQL-standard `DATE` type, then use Java class `LocalDate`.

Generally best to use  half-open definition of a span of time, where the beginning is inclusive while the ending is exclusive. This allows spans to nearly abut one another without gaps or overlap. So never use the SQL command `BETWEEN` for date-time ranges, as it is fully-closed (both beginning and ending are inclusive).

Get today’s date as seen in the wall-clock time used by the people of a particular region (a time zone).

`BST` is not a real time zone. For British time, use `Europe/London`.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Europe/London" ) ;
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z ) ;
```

The SQL will look something like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM event_ 
WHERE ? >= start_
AND ? < end_
;
```

Fill in the placeholders.

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( 1 , today ) ;
myPreparedStatement.setObject( 2 , today ) ;
```

Load the date values from database into Java.

```
LocalDate start = myResultSet.getObject( … , LocalDate.class ) ;
```

## `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE`

The misnamed [`DATE`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm#CNCPT413) in the Oracle database actually represents a date with time-of-date without the context of a time zone or offset-from-UTC. As such, this type cannot represent a moment, a specific point on the timeline. It the value is noon on the 23rd of January next year, we cannot know if that is noon in Tokyo, Toulouse, or Toledo — all different moments several hours apart. This `DATE` type is akin to the SQL-standard type `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE`.

So for this data type, your question asking about time zones makes no sense. Apple and oranges. Involving time zones means you are tracking moments, specific points on the timeline. But the Oracle `DATE` cannot represent moments as discussed above.

To track moments, your should be using a column of a type akin to the SQL-standard `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`.

Comment: `LocalDate` only has year-month-day components; in Oracle a `DATE` data type has year-month-day-hour-minute-second components. Also, `!<` is not a valid operator in Oracle; you want `>=`.

Comment: @MT0 I added a section on that type now that the OP has identified that type specifically.